# mouse touch pad becomes unresponsive some times

Tags: 11.10, gnome, mouse, touchpad

I have a dual boot laptop with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10 loaded.Things have been working fine

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 from past 1.5 years, recently I came up with this problem that the touchpad stops responding  to movement i.e. touch of finger on it.

I thought it could be a hardware issue and started using Windows 7 on same system but then after conitnuous usage for many days I did not faced this issue on Windows 7 but upon a reboot the touch pad becomes unsensitive while working and in that situation my only way is to press Ctrl+Alt+T and open terminal issue sudo reboot and login again then the touchpad works.

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try to install synaptics touch pad driver

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`